# Unity Facebook SDK: Mach-o Linker Error when building in XCode

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Currently I'm trying to implement the facebook sdk but when I try to build in xCode I got this Error:

[image]

My Build Settings changes are:
Bitcode -> NO

Enable Modules (C and Objective-C) -> YES

Imported Facebook Framework folder:

[image]

Linked binaries with libaries

[image]

I'm using Unity Facebook SDK v7.11.1. In the release notes is written that this issue should be fixed... But when I try to rollback to an older Version i get the same error. Any ideas?

I found some threads about this issue but nothing helps every Facebook sdk version throws this error.

My Unity Version is 2017.3.1f1

Comment: (1) did you link binaries with your libraries? (2) https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=j3UzJSRex_E

Comment: Yes I linked FBSDKCoreKit, FBSDKSHareKit, Bolts, FBSDKLoginKit and FBAudienceNetwork under Build Phases

Comment: I fixed it https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/unity?